# Jquery keyup issue with dropdown menus?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code, basically I have `<input id="register_username" type="text" name="username">` and I want to check if the users already exist in the database or not. The code works perfectly when the user type a username, but sometimes some browsers (for example Firefox) gives the user drop down menu and let them choose some values they already entered in the past (such as their name). The problem is when the chose the username from the drop down menu, the `keyup` function does not work. How can I fix this problem ?

```
$("#register_username").live('keyup', function() {

    $.post('scripts/register/register_check.php', {
        checkusername: $('#register_username').val()
    }, function(data) {
        if (data == "good") {
            //do something
        } else {
            //do the other thing
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: By the way, [`.live()` is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/); use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Comment: or you can force users to type it automatically by setting `autocomplete="off"` attribute to the form

Answer (score 1):

I don't think all browers if any triggers an event after choosing an option from an autocomplete dropdown.

Your best bet is to use [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) which will trigger after the element loses focus. For example, when the user chooses an autocomplete option and move on to the next field.

Comment: what in case if that was the last field ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [onblur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event to fire whenever the field loses focus.